# Create PDFMake table cells from angularjs .forEach loop over array

Tags: angularjs, pdfmake

The code below renders the following PDF: [Link to PDF on Google Docs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9COonOvl5koM0hGSnhlRFpWSDQ/view?usp=sharing).  (I was not allowed to paste a picture into this post)

There are song titles and chord progressions for each song.  What I am looking for is to have a single row for each song/chords cells.  In the example I hard coded one last song in the code to show what it should render like.  Each song should have its own table row.  I have been at it for hours and can't figure it out ...hoping it's a simple solution and I'm just missing something pretty obvious.

Thanks for any help.

```
    //Fired when SET header clicked to generate PDF
    $scope.openPDF = function (SetName, setSongs) {                       
        songTitles = [];
        songChords = [];

        angular.forEach(setSongs, function(value, key) {            
            songTitles.push({ text: value.Title, style: 'tableHeader'});
            songChords.push({ text: value.Chords, style: 'tableHeader'});
        });

        var docDefinition = 
        {       
           pageOrientation: 'landscape',

           content: [
             { text: 'SET 01', style: 'firstLine'},
             { text: SetName, style: 'secondLine' },                 
                {  
                    table: 
                    {
                        headerRows: 0,                            
                        body: 
                        [                       
                          [songTitles, songChords],['American Girl', 'D - E - G - A']
                        ]
                    }
                }
           ],

           styles: {
             firstLine: {
               fontSize: 32,
               bold: true,
               alignment: 'center'
             },
             secondLine: {
               fontSize: 15,
               bold: true,
               alignment: 'center'
             },
           }

        };//End docDefinition

        //Generate PDF
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();

    }; //END Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it out ...posting solution in case it helps someone.

Link to PDF created using the function below: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9COonOvl5koR09aNkRZUHpPczA

All data is pulled from a MySQL database...so there is a table of songs with various attributes (Title, Artist, main chord structure, etc) - then a table of sets which contain three setlists per set.

```
    //Fired when SET header clicked to generate PDF
    $scope.openPDF = function (setList, setSongs, setNumber) {                       
        songRows = [];

        angular.forEach(setSongs, function(value, key) {            
            songRows.push({Title: value.Title, Chords: value.Chords, WhoStarts: value.WhoStarts});                
        });

        var items = songRows.map(function(item) {
         return [(100 + songRows.indexOf(item) + 1).toString().slice(-2) + '.', item.Title, item.Chords, item.WhoStarts];
        });

        var docDefinition = 
        {       
           pageOrientation: 'landscape',

           content: 
           [
                { text: setNumber, style: 'firstLine'},
                { text: setList.EventDate + ' - ' + setList.SetName + ' @ ' + setList.Venue + '\n\n', style: 'secondLine' },                 
                {  
                    style: 'songRow',
                    table: 
                    {                                                   
                      body: 
                      [
                        [                             
                          { text: '------' },
                          { text: '--------------------------------------' },
                          { text: '--------------------------------------' },
                          { text: '--------------------------------------' },  
                        ]
                      ].concat(items)                         
                    }
                }
           ],

           styles: {
             firstLine: {
               fontSize: 32,
               bold: true,
               alignment: 'center'
             },
             secondLine: {
               fontSize: 15,
               bold: true,
               alignment: 'center'
             },
             songRow: {
               fontSize: 18,
               bold: true,
               alignment: 'center',                   
             },
           }

        };//End docDefinition

        //Generate PDF
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    } //END Generate PDF Function
```

Comment: Hi, Its a good to generte the PDF. My requirement is that each page will have a header with 3 lines and in bottom of page with table. In this way, array  for which pdf has to be generated. Please Help me.

Comment: Hi Nitin...I'm sorry but I'm not a very good developer...I don't think I can help you.  You really should create a new question I think ... this is an old post and I htink what you are asking for is a new question.  Sorry I can't help.  Good luck!!